# "Literal replace" in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a way to perform a "literal replacing" in SymPy, which matches exactly the pattern?
For example, for the expression `exp(I*theta)+exp(-I*theta)`, I would like to replace only exp(I*t) to zero without replacing exp(-I*t)
A minimal example would be

```
from sympy import *
f=exp(I*t)+exp(-I*t)
```

Clearly, `subs` will not work

```
f.subs((exp(I*t),0))
```

because it also replaces `exp(-I*t)` with infinity.

Comment: By "literal", did you try regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `xreplace` method:

```
f.xreplace({exp(I*t):0})
```

Returns:

```
exp(-t*I)
```

[Here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.xreplace) is the documentation for reference.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the replace method --

```
t = 2
f = exp(I * t) + exp(-I * t)
f = f.replace(exp(I * t), 0)
print(f)
```

outputs:

```
exp(-2*I)
```

hope this helps!